# JFrame not opening on Macs

Tags: java, macos

I have some Java software which works perfectly on windows.  Unfortunately, when I try to run it on a mac, the software runs ( in as much as the white dot appears next to the icon in the dock), but the main JFame for the sofware, or anything else for that matter, does not open.

The software is written in Java 7, but also works on Java 8 on my own windows pc.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem? Create a simple java application using frames and see if it contains the same bug.

Comment: When you say wont open do you get an error?

Comment: I'm relying on other people to mac test my software as I don't own one myself.  I send a .jar file and rely on the feedback they give me. I didn't think of displaying error messages because I wasn't getting any in windows.  It seems obvious  now you mention it.  I will give this a go.  Thanks.